# my Jquery script is not working. the bar(icon) does not show navigation bar contents when clicked on (on a mobile device)

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
      <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
            <nav>
                <ul

    >
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about2.html">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contacts,html">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="projects.html">projects</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="menu-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars "></i>

                </div>
            </header>

            <script>
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                        $('.nav').toggleClass('active')
                    })
                })
                </script>
        </head>
```

**beginning of css code**

```
style
                   @media(max-width:767px){
    header{
        padding:0 0px;
    }
    .menu-toggle{
        display:block;
        color:#1d4d77;
    }
    header nav{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        height:calc(100vh-50px);
        width:100%;
        background:#fff;
        top:50px;
        left:-100%;
        transition: 0.5s;


    }
    header nav.active{
        left:0;
        display:block;

    }
    header nav ul {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
    }
    header nav ul li a{
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(248, 248, 248);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. We also require that you tell us both what you were expecting and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just maybe, is because your selector ".nav" will search for a class called "nav". If you use a `<div class="nav">` it will work.
What you probably meant was

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                        $('nav').toggleClass('active')
                    })
                })
```